# Fullscreen Activity with titlebar backbutton

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen, android-notification-bar

I am making a webview client app for my RSS website. The webview and splashscreen are working great in theme.notitlebar.fullscreen. 
Because external links are opening in my webview, i want a back button in the titlebar. But i want to keep the full screen option, to remove the time and notifications, and the device buttons.

What i dont understand: Is it correct that the titlebar includes: the bar with time and notifications - bar with app name, back button and settings (extra) button - the device buttons (if available)?

If that is right. How can i add a new bar into the mainactivity with my webview client, with a back button in it.

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Actually giving a back button is totally depend on your requirements, you can show time and notification bar as well, and can also provide close button in place of back button which is a good way to show webview in your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image view. set src to back icon. and finish(); activity on imageview click.